# Is a monotonic function Riemann integrable even if it is discontinuous?

Tags: integration

I know that a monotonic function is integrable on $[a,b]$. I was wondering if I had a function with a discontinuity, then is it still considered a monotone function?

For example, say I had the cubic function  $x^3$ on some interval $[-3,3]$ with some discontinuity, say at $x=2$ there was a discontinuity, making $f(2)=28$. Is it still integrable? (Also, out of curiosity, would I still call $x^3$ an odd function, since I can't test that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for the point of discontinuity?)

Comment: It is still integrable. The discontinuity happens on a set of measure zero. (By the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability).

Comment: It is still integrabe, but your modified function is no longer monotone. An example of a monotone function which has a discontinuity would be, to modify your example slightly, $f(x) = x$ on $[-\infty,2]$ and then $f(x) = x^3$ on $[2,\infty]$.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: I'm looking for an odd, Riemann integrable function that is not continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Is there a way to make the example you gave in your comment be valid by somehow introducing point symmetry so its an odd function?

Comment: How about $x^3 -1$ for $[-\pi, 0)$, define it as $0$ for $x=0$, and $x^3 +1$ for $(0,\pi]$. Monotonic, discontinuous, integrable and odd, because $f(-x) = (-x)^3 +1 = -x^3 +1 = -(x^3 -1) = -f(x)$ for $x \in (0, \pi]$ (likewise for $x \in [-\pi, 0)$).

Comment: @MarkFantini: Thank you. I can see that it is an odd function by noting that it has point symmetry, but I am having some trouble algebraically showing it. I know I need to show that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, but I notice that for $f(-x)$ you use $x\in [-\pi,0)$, but for $-f(x)$ you use $x\in (0,\pi]$. Can I ask how you knew which part of the function to use?

EDIT: Nevermind; I just understood. Since one is $-x$, we have to use the other interval. Thanks again Mark!

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted what I wrote. In full detail, write it like this. For $x \in (0,\pi]$ we have that $-x \in [-\pi, 0)$. But for $-x \in [-\pi,0)$ we have that $$f(-x) = -(-x)^3 -1 = x^3 -1 = -(x^3+1) = -f(x),$$ valid for $x \in (0,\pi]$. Likewise, for $x \in [-\pi,0)$ we have that $-x \in (0,\pi]$, therefore $$f(-x) = (-x)^3 +1 = -x^3 +1 = -(x^3 -1) = -f(x),$$ valid for $x \in [-\pi,0)$. I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer containing this.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{align} x^3 -1, & \quad x \in [-\pi,0), \\ 0, & \quad x = 0, \\ x^3 +1, & \quad x \in (0,\pi]. \end{align} \right.$$ Then $f$ is monotonic, discontinuous, integrable, and odd.

For $x \in (0,\pi]$ we have that $-x \in [-\pi, 0)$. But for $-x \in [-\pi,0)$ we have that $$f(-x) = -(-x)^3 -1 = x^3 -1 = -(x^3+1) = -f(x),$$ valid for $x \in (0,\pi]$.

Likewise, for $x \in [-\pi,0)$ we have that $-x \in (0,\pi]$, therefore $$f(-x) = (-x)^3 +1 = -x^3 +1 = -(x^3 -1) = -f(x),$$ valid for $x \in [-\pi,0)$.